# Failed to connect to example.com port 4000 Spree commerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

After installing Spree Commerce and running [these commands](https://dev-docs.spreecommerce.org/getting-started/installation#installation), I am unable to access my domain `http://example.com:4000/` or `http://example.com:4000/admin`. 
When I run:
`curl example.com:4000` I got: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to example.com port 4000 after 27 ms: Connection refused`. 
What is the reason I cannot access Spree Commerce on port 4:000 after fresh install and how can I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no point for accessing - `http://example.com:4000`. As per the spree [documentation](https://dev-docs.spreecommerce.org/getting-started/installation#hello-spree-commerce), you should use `http://localhost:4000` for accessing the spree application.

For [Backend](https://dev-docs.spreecommerce.org/getting-started/installation#logging-into-the-admin-panel)

For [APIs](https://dev-docs.spreecommerce.org/getting-started/installation#connecting-to-the-api)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have this installed on Ubuntu on a domain name. So for me to access that, I use my domain name (i.e, here referred to as example.com).

Comment: Checkout nginx puma example file [here](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/docs/nginx.md), this might help you to setup the correct configuration. Moreover, make sure you have DNS mapped correctly for the domain you are trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

Firewall could be the principal problem. Have you tried checking opened ports?

List the current Iptables rules

```
sudo iptables -L
```

Add an Iptable rule (for example to open a Mysql port 3306)

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

Remove an Iptable rule

```
sudo iptables -D INPUT -p tcp --dport xxxx -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I don't have any firewall enabled. But I suspect the problem is related to the Nginx configuration file which I am not sure how it should look like to run Spree.